# Validating bundles of XMLs with inconsistent structure

Tags: neural-networks, data-preprocessing, word-embedding, text-classification, bag-of-words

**The problem:**

We have a large number of XML bundles, and each bundle needs to meet certain criteria to be considered valid; specifically, certain values (or types of values) should belong to certain tags in the XMLs within a bundle. One option is, of course, to simply parse the files and substring/regex-search for the data we're interested in. I'm hesitant to proceed this way for a couple of reasons:

- A hard-coded set of acceptable values/regular expressions might be comically large, and still incomplete.
- Some data have multiple representations in the bundle (i.e. different tags in different files that, for our business needs, have logically equivalent values), and again, not all representations are necessarily known.

**The ideal solution (?):**

We'd be able to construct a neural network that receives the XML strings, one input neuron for the concatenated bundle or one for each file within, and bada bing bada boom, a probability is output for each of our validation criterion. If all the criteria are above a certain threshold, the bundle is considered valid. I believe binary cross-entropy and sigmoid would be the appropriate loss and output activation functions, respectively, for such a perfect-world network, but I'd happily take correction there too.

**The subsequent problem:**

As I understand it, NN's aren't exactly literate beings, at least in the conventional sense. One approach I can (kind of) understand to make text digestible to them is the [bag-of-words model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model). It seems to me, though, that this approach is better suited for "regular" text than something like XML. This led to me deliriously contemplating an adapted "bag-of-tags" model, in which the "vocabulary" consists of all the available XML tags, and the text nodes are embedded (somehow) in matrix/tensor positions corresponding to their parent tags, but I haven't started experimenting with that yet, and I'm not sure it even makes any sense.

**Finally, my question(s):**

Is this impossible? Should I go back to school for several years to solve the problem at hand? Or are there recommended ways of preprocessing XML inputs to validate them with neural networks?